# SSH works in Terminal but nor in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to execute a script I uploaded to an AWS instance.  If I run the following command in my MacBook Terminal, it succeeds:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ec2/my.pem ec2-user@ec2-<address>.amazonaws.com "chmod u+x ./myScript.sh"
```

I ported the same command to a simple shell script on my local machine, where I pass in the information:

```
#!/bin/sh
# myLocalScript.sh

host=$1
pem=$2
fileName=$3

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $pemkey ec2-user@$host "chmod u+x ./$fileName"
```

When I run it using this command:

```
sh myLocalScript.sh ec2-user@ec2-<address>.amazonaws.com ~/.ec2/my.pem myScript.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Identity file ec2-user@ec2-<address>.amazonaws.com not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname chmod u+x ./myScript.sh: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 for this question.  You included background, your script AND the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `$pem` not `$pemkey`.

Additionally, you should get into the habit of double-quoting variables, except in very special situations where you really want an empty variable to "disappear".